# Treat Clojure macro as a function

Tags: macros, clojure

How can I cause a Clojure macro to act as a function, so I can pass it as an argument for example?  I would expect to have to wrap it somehow.

I would not expect the wrapped version to behave exactly the same as the original macro (differences of call by name vs call by value), but it would be useful in a few cases where this wasn't important.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can just wrap it in a function.

Consider this (silly) implementation of a squaring function as a macro:

```
(defmacro square [x]
  (list * x x))
```

Passing it directly as an arg won't work, as you know:

```
user=> (map square [1 2 3 4 5])
java.lang.Exception: Can't take value of a macro: #'user/square (NO_SOURCE_FILE:8)
```

But wrapping it in a function will do the trick:

```
user=> (map #(square %) [1 2 3 4 5])
(1 4 9 16 25)
```

Alternatively (and quite a bit more evil-ly), you could make another macro to do a more generic wrapping:

```
(defmacro make-fn [m] 
  `(fn [& args#] 
    (eval `(~'~m ~@args#))))

user=> (map (make-fn square) [1 2 3 4 5])
(1 4 9 16 25)
```

I'd stick with the normal function wrapping, and skip this last hack! :)

Comment: Hm, this doesn't work for variadic macros:
user=> (apply #(or %) [true false false])
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong number of args (3) passed to: user$eval3$fn (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)

Comment: 3 points: (1) the best way to solve this example is `(some identity [true false false])`, (2) if you know the number of params & make that explicit, it'll do the trick: `(apply #(or %1 %2 %3) [true false false])`, (3) the hacky `make-fn` works: `(apply (make-fn or) [true false false])`

Answer (score 5):

There is a dangerous, deprecated macro that you should not ever use. :-P

http://clojure.github.com/clojure-contrib/apply-macro-api.html

Comment: Hm, this gives me a stack overflow when I attempt this example in Clojure 1.2: (apply-macro or? [true false false]))

Comment: Ugh it's true, the problem is with the private function spread in the apply-macro ns: it is a copy of a obsolete clojure.core one, if you replace it with the actual version [the hack works](https://gist.github.com/986321)

Comment: The diff is curious (rest [1]) -> (), (next [1]) -> nil. The first with the nil? as guard predicate to stop recursion raises the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

For the crazy macro **make-fn**, how about the one below? 
It should work as well, and hopefully easier to understand.

```
(defmacro make-fn [m] 
 `(fn [& args#]
    (eval 
      (cons '~m args#))))
```